# Reading 2 rows together from SQL Server table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a table which has the following data:

```
Record Type             MID             CvvId            Date           Amount
-------------        ----------        -------------   -------------   ---------
    2E                8715613516                         2014-25-03        27.12
    3E                asd5156154485         M                    
    2E                8751651650                         2014-25-03        27.13
    3E                asd5165434485         S
```

No I have to read the values of this table and insert it another table, having columns as:

```
MID, CvvId, Date, Amount.
```

Now for every record of Record Type **"2E"**, the row just after that would be always of record type **"3E"**

For columns MID, CvvId, Date, Amount I have to use the record type "2E". For CvvId, I have to use the record type "3E". After every 2E record, I would get a 3E record. I have to write a stored procedure in SQL Server to insert this data into another table. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Can you show some sample of expected results, just to make sure this is clear?

Comment: Hello, you can not guarantee that the following row of a 2E row will be its 3E row. There must be a unique identity value only belonging to that 2 records.

Comment: The order in which you see results displayed in the output of a table is not guaranteed, if there is no ORDER BY used in displaying the data. Thus, as @Eralper said, you cannot guarantee that 2E will be followed by its corresponding 3E without either a identity value (unique ID column) or a specific ordering logic.

Comment: SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  The statement "the row right after" doesn't make sense.  You need a column that specifies the ordering.

Comment: Is there a way to update the CvvId of every "2E" row, from the the CvvId of the next "3E" row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work. As recommended above, added a new auto-increment (not necessarily P.k) field as Tid. and wrote the following query: -

SELECT p.MID, LEAD(p.CvvId) OVER (ORDER BY p.Tid) NextCvv,
LEAD(p.RecordType) OVER (ORDER BY p.Tid) NextRecordType
FROM table p

after filtering through the record set, on some business conditions, it worked. Thanks all for help!.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your table by adding a transactionId column which is unique for both 2E and 3E records as follows

```
create table tableE(
TId int,
rtype   varchar(20),
MID varchar(20),
CvvId   varchar(20),
date    date,
amount  decimal(18,2))
```

Then following SELECT statement will help you combine them into a single row

```
select * 
from tableE t1
inner join tableE t2 on t1.tid = t2.tid
where t1.rtype = '2E' and t2.rtype = '3E'
```

Comment: This table is being populated from a flat source file, using SSIS. cannot add a Tid column as mentioned by you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a process for doing this using `bulk insert`.  As suggested in another answer, you want to change the definition of the underlying table to have an identity column:

```
create table atable (
    atableId int not null identity(1, 1) primary key,
    rtype   varchar(20),
    MID varchar(20),
    CvvId   varchar(20),
    date    date,
    amount  decimal(18,2)
);
```

Then, define a view on this table that excludes the identity:

```
create view v_atable as 
   select rtype, mid, cvvid, date, amount
   from atable;
```

Now, use `bulk insert` into the *view*.  This will generate an auto-incrementing identity value for each row.  You then have an ordering and can identify the next row.